# IP GeoLocation in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, geolocation, ip

How I can geolocate an IP in VBNET?

I want to know the city and country of an IP (better if I can get more dates but I only need that two)

I can do it with any Class? or I need to found a good service to send Post data? in that case, can give a easy service to send/receive the data?

Any example of how to do this using a web API or Classes please?

PS: For VB.NET

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class that will do that for you. It is too high level task and too specific at the same time. You can choose either of approaches:

1. Have a local database and just query it. [Like this](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite).
2. Use online service, there are lots of them. Some may have API, some will require raw HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks, in that case I choose to use an online service, but I don't want to choose wrong (I mean to choose a newbie website that will die in some time) so can you tell me a good online service?